# How do you get hyperbola by squaring a bell?

Tags: normal-distribution

This is a Gaussian bell (aka normal distribution).

[image]

Its square, I belive looks the same. Yet, I see that chi-square distribution, which is a sum of k such bell squares, looks like

[image]

Take a look at yellow chi-squared, with k=1. It should be just single bell squared. But, it looks like a hyperbola instead of Gaussian. Why?

**PS** I read that normally-distributed signal generates a uniformly distributed power. Is it the same kind of magic?

Comment: This is a psychological question: "Why is my intuition contradicted by mathematical facts?" It's better to do the algebra first and then adjust your graphical intuition accordingly.

Comment: Here is a simple algebra. Let's normal distribution is 1,2,1 -- a pretty nice Gaussian curve. Its square is 1,4,1 -- exactly the same Gaussian curve. Ok?

Comment: The normal is already very concentrated in a neighbourhood of $0$. Squaring magnifies that concentration a great deal.

Comment: @Val - That's example of a sample. It could be coming from any distribution.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: Wait. What do you mean by "concentrated"? Do distributions care where they are? You have Gaussian(zero)=x. You square it. Chi-square has x^2 at 0. Which concentration are you talking about? We do not have any division there.

Comment: You might be thinking that the density of the distribution of the square of a random variable is the square of the density of the distribution of this random variable. It is not. In particular the chi-square density with k=1 is not the square of the gaussian bell.

Comment: @Val - the square of the standard normal distribution (mean = 0, standard deviation = 1) has a $\chi^2_1$ distribution. If you square an arbitrary Gaussian distribution, you'll get something more complicated.

Comment: @Val: For a perhaps similar reason, people often draw $y=x^2$ incorrectly, not "flat" enough.

Comment: @HansEngler I was always sure that Gaussian = normal distribution. But, anyway, isn't your clue that general Gaussian != normal is different from the Did's answer, who says that the problem is that square of distribution != distribution of squares?

Comment: @Val. Read what I wrote. "Gaussian" is the same as "normal". But "Standard normal" is a special case. Did's correct comment has nothing to do with this and is possibly the clue to your confusion.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Elaborate. How relationship between x and $x^2$ explains the concentration, inequality between Gaussian and normal distribution and inequality between distrbution of squares and distribution squared?

Comment: @HansEngler, I have presented the example of non-standard normal distribution 1,2,1. Squaring it does not change the shape of the bell. The bell remains a bell. I do not see which kind of parameters you need to change this fact.

Comment: Val: Squaring **WHAT**? At the risk of repeating my comment, what do you call squaring a distribution?

Comment: I have no idea what I can square if not samples. Ok, I can square them along X or Y axis. But, anyway, the Bell results. Squaring just stretches points in X or Y derection.

Comment: Val: That's a new one... Where is there a *sample* in your question?

Comment: @Did, see my edit. Samples are along X or Y axis. I do not know but it seems that it does not matter. Now I think that they are long X axis. The vertical Y axis should say "how much" do we have such samples. So, squaring will stretch the distribution along X axis. I initially believed that it will make the distribution peaks higher and narrower. But it does not matter. I do not see how hyperbola results from squaring a bell.

Comment: This is what I feared: you square the density and this leads you nowhere since squaring the density has no meaning. I will post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a random variable $X$ with density $f$, say $X$ gaussian, and $Y=X^2$. Then $Y\geqslant0$ almost surely and, for every $y\geqslant0$, $[Y\leqslant y]=[-\sqrt{y}\leqslant X\leqslant\sqrt{y}]$ hence
$$
P[Y\leqslant y]=\int_{-\sqrt{y}}^{\sqrt{y}}f(x)\mathrm dx.
$$
Differentiating this yields the density of $Y$, namely, for every $y\geqslant0$,
$$
g(y)=\frac{f(\sqrt{y})+f(-\sqrt{y})}{2\sqrt{y}}.
$$
When $X$ is normal (centered or not), $f$ is continuous at $0$ hence the behaviour of $g$ at $0$ is
$$
g(y)\sim\frac{f(0)}{\sqrt{y}}.
$$
Note finally that $f^2$ is rarely a density function.

**Edit:** Recall that an integral depending on a parameter, say
$$
J(y)=\int_{u(y)}^{v(y)}w(x)\mathrm dx,
$$
has derivative
$$
J'(y)=w(v(y))v'(y)-w(u(y))u'(y).
$$

Comment: I am not ready to consume this. But, thanks anyway. I see that you based your proof on the standard normal whereas enemy in comments suggested that discrepancy of X^2 from from normal distribution stems from non-standard Gaussians.

Comment: The centering or decentering of gaussians has little to do with the $c/\sqrt{y}$ behaviour, when $y\to0$, that my answer exhibits.

Comment: Thanks confirming that. But, unfortunately, I am too stupid to comprehend your answer. The $\sqrt y$ appears out of blue. I look at it like illusion, when a thing materializes out of nothing in the hands of magician. I guess that if we had power of 1 instead of two, i.e. y=x^1, you'd get g(y) = f(x)/y.

Comment: Re the appearance of $\sqrt{y}$, see my Edit. To sum up, $y\mapsto\pm\sqrt{y}$ is the inverse of $x\mapsto x^2$ one started with and the final $c/\sqrt{y}$ is more or less its derivative.

Comment: @Val - I am upvoting your last comment because there is some truth in it.

Comment: BTW, I read that normally-distributed signal generates a uniformly distributed power. The power is a square of the signal. Is it the same kind of magic?

Comment: New problem $\implies$ new question (hopefully, with more details).

Answer (score 0):

Let $Z$ be standard normal, or more generally a normal with mean $0$. But in fact we will use almost no properties of the normal.

Let $Y=Z^2$. We want to show that the density function $f_Y(y)$ of $Y$ is very large for $y$ near $0$. This density function is approximately $\frac{F_Y(y)}{y}$.

We have $F_Y(y)=2\Pr(Z\le \sqrt{y})$. For $y$ close to $0$, the density function of $Z$ is close to a non-zero constant $c$.

Thus $F_Y(y)$ is approximately $2c\sqrt{y}$. It follows that near $0$, $\frac{F_Y(y)}{y}$ is very large.